# Apache Shiro HashedCredentialsMatcher generates wrong salt

Tags: java, shiro

I'm facing the problem that Shiro shows some odd behavior in converting a byte 
array to a salt.

I started to implement all classes involved in the process into my application which are:

- org.apache.shiro.realm.AuthenticatingRealm
- org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.HashedCredentialsMatcher

Upon User creation the user password is hashed with a generated salt and then stored in my database:

```
import org.apache.shiro.crypto.hash.Sha256Hash;
import org.apache.shiro.crypto.RandomNumberGenerator;
import org.apache.shiro.crypto.SecureRandomNumberGenerator;

RandomNumberGenerator rng = new SecureRandomNumberGenerator();
Object salt = rng.nextBytes();
String hashedPasswordBase64 = new Sha256Hash(password, salt, 1024).toBase64();
```

shiro.ini looks like this:

```
# SALTED JDBC REALM

saltedJdbcRealm=com.mycompany.ssp.SaltedJdbcRealm

dataSource = org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
dataSource.databaseName = Self-Service-Portal
dataSource.serverName = localhost
dataSource.portNumber = 5432
dataSource.user = postgres
dataSource.password = admin

saltedJdbcRealm.dataSource = $dataSource
saltedJdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT umgmt_users.password, umgmt_users.salt FROM umgmt_users WHERE umgmt_users.user = ?

sha256Matcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.Sha256CredentialsMatcher

# base64 encoding, not hex in this example:
sha256Matcher.storedCredentialsHexEncoded = false
sha256Matcher.hashIterations = 1024

saltedJdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher = $sha256Matcher

################################################################################
# SECURITY MANAGER #

securityManager.realms = $saltedJdbcRealm
strategy = org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.FirstSuccessfulStrategy
securityManager.authenticator.authenticationStrategy = $strategy

################################################################################
```

my custom saltedJdbcRealm just overrides the doGetAuthenticationInfo. This code is from this blog [->](http://meri-stuff.blogspot.de/2011/04/apache-shiro-part-2-realms-database-and.html)

```
@Override
protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token) throws AuthenticationException {
    //identify account to log to
    UsernamePasswordToken userPassToken = (UsernamePasswordToken) token;
    String username = userPassToken.getUsername();

    if (username == null) {
        log.debug("Username is null.");
        return null;
    }

    // read password hash and salt from db 
    PasswdSalt passwdSalt = getPasswordForUser(username);

    if (passwdSalt == null) {
        log.debug("No account found for user [" + username + "]");
        return null;
    }

    // return salted credentials
    SimpleAuthenticationInfo info = new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(username, passwdSalt.password, getName());
    info.setCredentialsSalt(new SimpleByteSource(passwdSalt.salt));

    return info;
}
```

Debugging after `return info` goes like this:

- AuthenticatingRealm.java: Mehtod: assertCredentialsMatch()
- HashedCredentialsMatcher.java: Method: doCredentialsMatch()
- HashedCredentialsMatcher.java: Method: hashProvidedCredentials()

Looking for the error I ended up finding it here in
org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.HashedCredentialsMatcher.java:

```
protected Object hashProvidedCredentials(AuthenticationToken token, AuthenticationInfo info) {
    Object salt = null;
    if (info instanceof SaltedAuthenticationInfo) {

        // STOP HERE AND SEE BELOW PART 1!!!

        salt = ((SaltedAuthenticationInfo) info).getCredentialsSalt();

        // STOP HERE AND SEE BELOW PART 2!!!

    } else {
        //retain 1.0 backwards compatibility:
        if (isHashSalted()) {
            salt = getSalt(token);
        }
    }
    return hashProvidedCredentials(token.getCredentials(), salt, getHashIterations());
}
```

**Part 1:**

lets take a look at the variable info:

[image]

The full byte array is the following:

```
57 109 102 43 65 87 118 88 70 76 105 82 116 104 113 108 116 100 101 108 79 119 61 61
```

which correctly represents the salt in my database:

```
9mf+AWvXFLiRthqltdelOw==
```

Next Step in the code is to extract the Salt from the info variable and store it in the variable salt of type Object.

**Part 2:**

looking at the variable salt after this line:

```
salt = ((SaltedAuthenticationInfo) info).getCredentialsSalt();
```

executed I get this result:

```
OW1mK0FXdlhGTGlSdGhxbHRkZWxPdz09
```

**Edit:**

I did another example and show you the 2 methods that 1) hash the submitted password 2) take the password from database for comparison & that they are not 
the same:

I start off with 2 variables, token (submitted password) & info (stored password information):

[image]

**Stored Credentials:**

[image]

credentials:

```
d5fHxI7kYQYtyqo6kwvZFDATIIsZThvFQeDVidpDDEQ
```

storedBytes before decoding:

```
100 53 102 72 120 73 55 107 89 81 89 116 121 113 111 54 107 119 118 90 70 68 65 84 73 73 115 90 84 104 118 70 81 101 68 86 105 100 112 68 68 69 81 61
```

storedBytes after decoding:

```
119 -105 -57 -60 -114 -28 97 6 45 -54 -86 58 -109 11 -39 20 48 19 32 -117 25 78 27 -59 65 -32 -43 -119 -38 67 12 68
```

hash:

```
7797c7c48ee461062dcaaa3a930bd9143013208b194e1bc541e0d589da430c44
```

**Submitted Credentials:**

[image]

char[] credentials:

```
[0] = 1
[1] = 2
[2] = 3
```

byte[] bytes:

```
50 69 81 77 57 55 80 53 53 112 89 52 122 69 78 54 57 98 53 56 82 65 61 61
```

which is `2EQM97P55pY4zEN69b58RA==` and this is whats inside the database

cachedBase64:

```
MkVRTTk3UDU1cFk0ekVONjliNThSQT09
```

return value is this hash:

```
af9a7ef0ea9fa4d93eae1ca5d16c03c516f4822ec3e9017f14f694175848a6ab
```

As the 2 Hash values are not the same I get why my Application is telling me wrong password BUT I created this user with the password 123 using the code above (first code block)

**Edit End**

So does anyone know why the hash calculation is not giving the same hash value for the same password??? Or what else I might have done wrong (i doubt that the shiro code is wrong so it may be something wrong in my code with generation the password hash/salt or shiro.ini configuration?)

Comment: `looking at the variable salt I get this result:` what does that mean?  The variable `salt`, it should be the `SimpleByteSource` that is #944 on your debug screenshot.  Is that not the case?  The code for `SimpleAuthenticationInfo` is here: https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.1/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/shiro/authc/SimpleAuthenticationInfo.html

Comment: I mean this line: `salt = ((SaltedAuthenticationInfo) info).getCredentialsSalt();` between the Stop Part1 & Part 2 Sections. The variable is assigned there but with the wrong value. I updated the part above for better understading

Comment: but the variable `salt` is a what?  It should be the same `SimpleByteSource` as you saw in `Part 1`.

Comment: Well the official "shiro-code" sets it as type Object `Object salt = null;` but I will try to check if that may be the cause

Comment: It's declared as Object, but what is it at runtime?

Comment: at runtime it is `SimpleByteSource` but still its not what comes out when you "translate" the bytes to characters somehow

Comment: It should be the same (as in same instance, `==` ) as in Part 1.  Is it possible character encodings are getting confused?

Comment: The "wrong" salt is the base64 encoded version of my original salt (from the database) but I dont understand why it gets encoded because this will cause the comparison to fail due to the fact that the salt inside the databse is not base64 encoded. Or i encode the salt with base 64 before writing it into my database so I dont have to touch the shiro code again ;)

Comment: Maybe it should be.  Salt is an arbitrary set of bytes, depending on the algo.  It may not always be serializable to character data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ufff, after a little more playing around with those functions I found the solution why the submitted password is hashed with a wrong salt value

I added 3 lines to the method `hashProvidedCredentials` inside

**org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.HashedCredentialsMatcher.java**

```
protected Object hashProvidedCredentials(AuthenticationToken token, AuthenticationInfo info) {
    Object salt = null;
    if (info instanceof SaltedAuthenticationInfo) {
        salt = ((SaltedAuthenticationInfo) info).getCredentialsSalt();
        
        // Get base64 Decoder
        java.util.Base64.Decoder Decoder = java.util.Base64.getDecoder();
        // decode salt from database
        byte[] encodedJava8 = null;
        encodedJava8 = Decoder.decode(((SaltedAuthenticationInfo) info).getCredentialsSalt().getBytes());
        // save decoded salt value in previous salt Object
        salt = ByteSource.Util.bytes(encodedJava8);
        
        // The 3 steps above are nessecary because the Object salt is of type 
        // SimpleByteSource and:
        // - it holds a byte[] which holds the salt in its correct form
        // - it also holds a cachedBase64 encoded version of this byte[]
        //   (which is of course not the actual salt)

        // The Problem is that the next method call below that hashes the
        // submitted password uses the cachedBase64 value to hash the
        // passwort and not the byte[] which represents the actual salt

        // Therefor it is nessecary to:
        // - create SimpleByteSource salt with the value from the database
        // - decode the byte[] so that the cachedBase64 represents the actual salt
        // - store the decoded version of the byte[] in the SimpleByteSource variable salt
    } else {
        //retain 1.0 backwards compatibility:
        if (isHashSalted()) {
            salt = getSalt(token);
        }
    }
    return hashProvidedCredentials(token.getCredentials(), salt, getHashIterations());
}
```

Now the user submitted password on login is hashed the same way as it was when being generated this way:

```
RandomNumberGenerator rng = new SecureRandomNumberGenerator();
Object salt = rng.nextBytes();
//Now hash the plain-text password with the random salt and multiple
//iterations and then Base64-encode the value (requires less space than Hex):
String hashedPasswordBase64 = new Sha256Hash(password, salt, 1024).toBase64();
```

*Note: This is not the final version of password hashing. Salt is going to be at least 256bit & iterations are going to be around 200k-300k.*

#### Having the problem solved, I narrowed down the problem to 4 possible options:

**1)**

There is a major Error in the shiro code (HashedCredentialsMatcher.java) (at least from my point of view it is) because password varification using a salt will always fail this way (see my description inside the code block).

**2)**

I either uses the wrong CredentialsMatcher for hased & salted passwords and I have no clue which one to use instead.

**3)**

My Implementation of the `doGetAuthenticationInfo` Method in my custom Realm has an error. For my Custom Realm I used this tutorial:
[Apache Shiro Part 2 - Realms, Database and PGP Certificates](http://meri-stuff.blogspot.de/2011/04/apache-shiro-part-2-realms-database-and.html)

**4)**

I made a mistake on creation of the password hash (although that code is from the official Apache Shiro Website [Link](http://shiro.apache.org/realm.html)

From my Point of view the options 1 & 4 are not the problem so its either 2 or 3 which cause this problem and make it nessecary to add some code to HashedCredentialsMatcher.java Method: hashProvidedCredentials()

### So concluding, does anyone have any idea on this issue just to get clarification??